# Recursive indentation in XTend

Tags: java, generator, xtext, xtend

Is it possible to control the indentation of recursive called methods in xtend? I have the following case:

```
def generateField(Field field)
    '''
    field «field.name» {
        description '«field.description»'
        label '«field.label»'
        «FOR alias : field.aliases BEFORE ' aliases {\n' SEPARATOR ',' AFTER '\n}'»
            «var f = alias.value as Field»«generateField(f)»
        «ENDFOR»
    }
    '''
```

The generated content looks like this:

```
    field name {
        description 'field Description'
        label 'fD'
        aliases {
            field nameA {
            description 'field Description'
            label 'fD'
        },
        field nameB {
                description 'field Description'
                label 'Fd'
        }}
```

The indentation of the brackets and the parameters is wrong generated. I expect auto indentation for recursively called methods.

I'm using Xtend 2.8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick for you.

```
def generateField(Field field) '''
    field «field.name» {
        description '«field.description»'
        label '«field.label»'
        «IF !aliases.isEmpty»
            aliases {
                «FOR a : field.aliases SEPARATOR ','»«f.generateField»«ENDFOR»
            }
        «ENDIF»
    }
'''
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. The only thing is, that there is no need for newline in the SEPARATOR section.

Comment: I fixed the code snippet and removed the newline from the separator